# one hot encoder: how to encode multible value of same category?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, one-hot-encoding

I am going to predict the box office of a movie. Assuming that there is only one categorical feature "actors" with values "A","B","C".And I enocde them as `[1,0,0],[0,1,0],[0,0,1]`,what if the movie has multiple actors,for example both A and B, should I encode it as `[1,1,0]` or `[1,0,0,0,1,0]`

Comment: almost certainly `[1,1,0]` or `[1,1,1]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should represent each as integers and `or` them together

```
A=int("100",2)
B=int("010",2)
C=int("001",2)
print A,B,C
movie = A|B
print movie
print bin(movie)
```